# Mysql delete from table where date is 'yesterday' but ignoring the time stamp

Tags: mysql

I have a table in Mysql which has column called 'dep_timestamp' which holds data in the following format (the data is received from a external source so can't be changed, and is displayed via web queries so can't be modified within that table)

`2015-05-12 19:18:00 +0100`

The database holds cancellations for booked taxi journeys which get pushed out to me from a central booking system in realtime. Throughout the day I will get any number of messages for cancelled journeys. A journey has a booked departure time `dep_timestamp` in its full format of `2015-05-12 19:18:00 +0100` that is used for reporting and all sort of other things.

Every day at 03:00 I want to delete all of the cancelled journeys that where due to depart 'yesterday' This means when my users do a query and ask what journeys have been cancelled today they only see stuff that has a booked departure of today.

I have an event setup on the server to delete rows older then 1 day using the following code;

`DELETE FROM db.canx_today WHERE 'dep_timestamp' < DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIME() , INTERVAL 1 DAY)`

That event is set to run every day at 03:00 and does without error.  However it takes the full date/time into consideration when running which means it only deletes the rows where the time & date are both older than one day.

If I swap `CURRENT_TIME` with `CURRENT_DATE` then the server throws this error; `Truncated incorrect datetime value: '2015-05-13 10:17:00 +0100'` which makes sense in so far that its looking for a full date/time string.

Is there a way to ignore the time element and just delete all rows that are from the previous day?

Comment: You could do `WHERE DATE(dep_timestamp) < CURDATE()`, but that would be slow due to the function call on the field value. Otherwise, best option is to calculate the full ending timestamp for the "cutoff" date.

Comment: @Uueerdo, that would also possibly delete records from 1 minute ago if a record exists at 23:59 and you run it at midnight.  But maybe that is the functionality they want?  I'm not quite sure from reading.

Comment: So not clear to me what the data range you are actually trying to delete for.  Are you saying you want to go back 24 hours from current_time, determine what date that is, then delete all records before that date?  That would mean oldest record in table would be between 24:00:00 and 47:59:59 old depending on what time of day this query is run (Or in your case, approximately 27 hours old since you are running at 03:00). Is this what you are looking for?  Also, you know that you should use backticks to escape your field names and not single quotes right?

Comment: Sorry I was eating and trying to update the question as you where replying. I've added some context and a bit of an explanation which should help better explain my logic.

Comment: yes backticks are used - this forum didnt like to format the text with the backtick in the middle of a code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate based on `CURRENT_DATE()` and just concatenate `00:00:00` to that value.

```
WHERE `dep_timestamp` < CONCAT(CURRENT_DATE(), ' 00:00:00')
```

Comment: So rather than reformatting the date I can just use this to trim it down to size. This solutions seems like it will have less overhead than the original answer I'd selected  (Sorry I'd missed this one) I will test this tonight and see if there is any noticeable difference.

Comment: @user3788685 Yes you "could" format `dep_timestamp` to match date without H:M:S, however this would not be an efficient query, in that you are making a comparison based on an un-indexable calculated value rather than an indexed value for `dep_timestamp`  The `CONCAT()` solution will likely give you better performance.

Comment: @MikeBrant his originally selected answer was mine; while I agree manipulating `dep_timestamp` (in any manner) would have poorer performance, I doubt this will perform any better or worse than the answer I suggested. Though I definitely would be interested if it did.

Comment: @Uueerdo I would agree that any performance differences between your approach and mine would likely be minimal at best, and likely only worth optimizing only at high volumes of interactions.  Don't know why the accepted answer was changed.  I in fact commented on your answer that your approach was an equally good approach to mine (in that you are comparing against unaltered `dep_timestamp` values).

Comment: I didn't notice any difference between the 2 answers after doing some testing, and the only reason I switched answers was due to the way im learning/understanding things. The way I see it MikeBrant answer is shorter in code and is only concatenating the time/date down to the bit I require, and @Uueerdo appeared to be completely reformatting the time/date string on the fly that's how I understood it anyway and I'm happy to to be best guided.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, but will only be noticeably faster than the one I originally put in the comments above if `dep_timestamp` is indexed.

```
WHERE `dep_timestamp` < DATE_FORMAT(curdate(), "%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00")
```

Since DATE_FORMAT() actually returns a string, this might be more efficient when indexes are actually needed:

```
WHERE `dep_timestamp` < CAST(DATE_FORMAT(curdate(), "%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00") AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: This is equally good approach to what I have posted, I think that you need to interval back 1 day though.

Comment: `dep_timestamp` is not indexed, but I could enable that without any problem at all. It's also worth saying that I would only ever expect a maximum of a few hundred records on the very worst day.

Comment: @MikeBrant he is not trying to delete everything "before yesterday", he is trying to delete yesterday on a daily basis.

Comment: @Uueerdo Ah yes.  Don;t know if I read it wrong at first or it became more clear after edit.

Comment: @user3788685 if the table is not going to grow more than a few hundred, I probably wouldn't worry about indexing `dep_timestamp` unless it ends up used as conditional criteria in frequently executed queries.

Comment: Cool thanks. Just ran a manual query and it worked cleanly I'll find out in the morning is the scheduled job runs ok and cleans up everything as it should. And yes just to clarify I'm deleting 'yesterday' every day at 3am.

Comment: @user3788685 A note, which I think is obvious but just in case... my suggestions delete everything before today. (On the plus side, if the script task gets missed one day, the next everything should be fine; no manual adjustments necessary to compensate for a missed task. On the minus side, if you wanted to keep certain older data, it won't work; but I don't think you do.)

Comment: Thank you. No I don't need to keep any old data from this table, and if I later did it would be pushed off to another table or db anyway. This is just for a snapshot of the current day. I already have another table for example which clears out journeys marked as complete every 10 min (meaning if a completed journey came in 1 sec before the event fired it would still be deleted) but that''s fine. This was only table I needed to keep things for a full day. Now you have pointed me to the right command I'll have a read of the MySQL docs.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM `canx_today` 
WHERE DATE(`dep_timestamp`) = DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Comment: For me this returns an error `Truncated incorrect datetime value: '2015-05-13 10:17:00 +0100'`